# How to install Python packages from python3-apt in PyCharm on Windows?

Tags: python, pycharm, apt

I'm on Windows and want to use the Python package `apt_pkg` in PyCharm.

On Linux I get the package by doing `sudo apt-get install python3-apt` but how to install `apt_pkg` on Windows?

There is no such package on PyPI.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to run `apt-get` in Windows; the package format and the supporting infrastructure is very explicitly Debian-specific.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you're looking for, but it's possible to use apt-offline on Windows to download the packages. However, you still need a Linux box to generate the sig file.

For example:

```
python apt-offline set vim-offline.sig --install-packages vim
```

Will not work:

***ERROR: This argument is supported only on Unix like systems with apt installed***

However, if you run that command on Linux first, the following command should work on Windows:

```
python apt-offline get vim-offline.sig -d vim
```

apt-offline source is available here:
https://github.com/rickysarraf/apt-offline

To build it, simply run:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

I got it to run with Python 3.8.2 on Windows 10.

*Note:* in the end of the day, you're just downloading a .deb package and it is simply an ar file containing a tarball and can be extracted with tools like 7-zip. However, if it contains a Linux binary (vim example), there isn't much you can do with it on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

One can use `chocolatey` the equivalent for windows.

https://chocolatey.org/install

add it to the windows PATH environment

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin
```

Restart python or anaconda. And is ready to use.

To install packages inside a `.py` script or a Jupiter notebook, use the syntax below

```
!choco install [package name]
```